# Convert a java.util.ArrayList of doubles to Matlab array by creating a java double[] array

Tags: java, arrays, matlab

I have a `com.mongodb.BasicDBList` that I need to convert to a Matlab array. The code below is done in Matlab and shows the type. All the elements in `arr` are the of the same type.

```
>> whos arr
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class                      Attributes

  arr       1x1                    com.mongodb.BasicDBList              

>> arr.size()
ans =

   304
>> v = arr.get(0);
>> whos v
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  v         1x1                 8  double
```

I have found a few ways of doing this:

> cell2mat(arr.toArray.cell)

Or:

```
newArr = javaArray('java.lang.Double', arr.size);
arr.toArray(newArr);
```

This second is an order of magnitude faster.It creates a Double[] array. Unfortunately Matlab doesn't treat this as a double automatically and thus I would need to convert it to a primitive double.

> double(newArr)

Which cancels out any speed gains from doing it this way compared to the first way.

If it would be possible to create a java `double[]` in Matlab it would solve my problem. I've tried the following, but since `double` is a primitive type there is no class associated with it and thus gives me an error.

```
newArr = javaArray('double', arr.size);
arr.toArray(newArr);
```

Is there a way to create an array of java doubles in matlab. The java code would be similar to `double[ ] arr = new double[x];`.

Comment: _"receive an java.util.ArrayList of double (The primitive, not Double)"_ -- this is not possible as you have stated it.  Please clarify.

Comment: It comes in as a `com.mongodb.BasicDBList` which extends `ArrayList`. All elements in the list are of type `double`. You can see here: http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/ for more info on `BasicDBList`. Does that make it possible ?

Comment: That extends `ArrayList<Object>`, so there must be _some_ wrapper class holding the values.

Comment: Everything I'm doing is in Matlab, and I see what you're saying, and agree that it's a little weird, but if `arr` is a `com.mongodb.BasicDBList` and I do `arr.get(0)` Matlab returns a `double` and not an `Object`. Is there another way I can check? I'm not very fluent in Java.

Comment: I'd venture and say that it's actually implemented as an `ArrayList<double>` since it's contents can be better represented as `double`.

Comment: `ArrayList<double>` is not a valid Java type